# How to use getAttribute and indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, indexof, getattribute

I am trying to make a fifteen puzzle, but the console says there is an error in funciton "movable". Function "movable" is supposed to return if it is the tile next to the unoccupied tile (not slatingly, but horizontal and vertical ways). And that consequently causes errors in "shuffle" and "move". Is there something wrong in this code? Sorry the code is a little long. Thanks.

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var unoccupied_x = 3;
var unoccupied_y = 3;

window.onload = function(){
    createPuzzle();
    document.getElementById("shufflebutton").onclick = shuffle;
};

function createPuzzle() {
    var pieceNum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            var tile = document.createElement("div");
            tile.classList.add("piece");

            tile.style.top = 100*i + "px";
            tile.style.left = 100*j + "px";
            tile.style.backgroundPosition = (0 - 100 * j) + "px"+ " " + (0 - 100 * i) + "px";
            tile.setAttribute("id","square" + "_" + j + "_" + i);
            pieceNum++;
            tile.innerHTML = pieceNum;

            tile.onclick = clickTile;

            if (i != 3 || j != 3){
              document.getElementById("puzzlearea").appendChild(tile);  
            }

        }
    }
}

function clickTile(){
    move(this);
}

function shuffle(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        var neighbors = searchNeighbors();
        var random = parseInt(Math.random() * neighbors.length);
        var tile = document.getElementById(neighbors[random]);

        move(tile);
    }
}

function searchNeighbors() {
    var up = 'square_' + unoccupied_x + "_" + (unoccupied_y - 1);
    var right = 'square_' + (unoccupied_x - 1) + "_" + unoccupied_y;
    var down = 'square_' + unoccupied_x + "_" + (unoccupied_y + 1);
    var left = 'square_' + (unoccupied_x - 1) + "_" + unoccupied_y;

    var neighborTiles = [up, down, left, right];
    var output = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < neighborTiles.length; i++){
        if(document.getElementById(neighborTiles[i]) != null){
            output.push(neighborTiles[i]);
        }    
    }
    return output;
}

function move(tile){
    if(movable(tile)){
        var originalX = parseInt(tile.style.left) /100;
        var originalY = parseInt(tile.style.top) / 100;
        var forSetAttributeX = unoccupied_x;
        var forSetAttributeY = unoccupied_y;

        tile.style.top = unoccupied_y * 100 + "px";
        tile.style.left = unoccupied_x * 100 + "px";
        unoccupied_x = originalX;
        unoccupied_y = originalY;
        tile.setAttribute("id", forSetAttributeX + "_" + forSetAttributeY);
    }
}

function movable(tile){
    var neighbors = searchNeighbors();
    return neighbors.indexOf(tile.getAttribute("id")) > -1 ;
}

})();
```

HTML is below (just in case)

```
<head>
    <title>Fifteen Puzzle</title>

    <link href="fifteen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="fifteen.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Fifteen Puzzle</h1>

    <p>
        The goal of the fifteen puzzle is to un-jumble its fifteen squares
        by repeatedly making moves that slide squares into the empty space.
        How quickly can you solve it?
    </p>

    <div id="puzzlearea"></div>

    <p id="controls">
        <button id="shufflebutton">Shuffle</button>
    </p>

    <div id="output"></div>

</body>
```

CSS is:

```
body{
    font-family: cursive, serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center;
}

#puzzlearea{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.piece{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your searchNeighbors method isn't creating the correct ids. Add 'square_' + to each.

```
var up = 'square_' + unoccupied_x + "_" + (unoccupied_y - 1);
var right = 'square_' + (unoccupied_x - 1) + "_" + unoccupied_y;
var down = 'square_' + unoccupied_x + "_" + (unoccupied_y + 1);
var left = 'square_' + (unoccupied_x - 1) + "_" + unoccupied_y;
```

Also highlight and unhighlight are undefined. You still have problems after that, but it will shuffle.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was missing 'square', and I added them to my code. Now, that works better, but when I run "shuffle", there is still errors... (I dont need to think of highlight and unhilight... sorry for the confusion)

Comment: shuffle() needs to not move if the tile is null.

`if(tile){
        move(tile);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Title stores an HTML element.
Your output which contains neighbours stores an array of strings.
So you are performing a wrong search with the indexOf

Then the if else is useless, you can directly return the statement

```
return neighbours.indexOf(...) > -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Based on your suggestion, I revised, but there is still a error in "moveable". (You can see my revision in the question) Is there still something wrong in this code.